# Android cannot import RecyclerView & CardView

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-recyclerview

I'm not able to import RecyclerView & CardView although it seems very trivial. This is the relevant part from `gradle.build` script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.+'
}
```

The sync & build tasks executes normally so it seems that the dependencies actually downloaded. And when in some activity I try to `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;` it's not recognising the package.

Maybe it's SDK API versions issues? Note I need min 11 and target max 22.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `buildToolsVersion`. See the below code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.2.2.jar')
    compile project(':Cropper')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':quickScroll')

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Add recent recyclerview which is in your sdk.
right click on **app --> Open Module Settings --> Dependencies** 
then on right side  click on plus button. Add library dependency and search recyclerview and then add it.

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yes! For some reason adding it directly in the build file didn't work for me.  But I removed it and added it back this way and now I can import it!

Comment: Thanks that did the trick on Android Studio 3.0 adding cardview thanks thanks thanks :D